# Find the perimeter of the locus of the point satisfying this condition

Tags: complex-numbers, coordinate-systems

> A point satisfies $$ \arg\left(\frac {z+i}{z-i}\right ) =\frac \pi 4 $$ 
>   We are asked to find the perimeter of the locus of the point.

I did actually got an answer but it isn't correct says my book.
**Here's my attempt**:
I put $z=x+iy$
$$\frac {x+i(y+1)}{x+i(y-1)} = \frac {x+i(y+1)}{x+i(y-1)} \cdot \frac {x-i(y-1)}{x-i(y-1)} \\ $$ On solving and taking the argument I get $$ x^2+y^2-2x-1=0$$ Obviously that represents a circle with radius $\sqrt 2$. So I conclude the perimeter must be $2\times \pi \sqrt 2$.

The answer is $\frac {3\pi} {\sqrt 2}$. Please do include what is the mistake in my method.
I heard the teacher saying that an easy and quick answer can be given by simple rotation. Please add an alternative answer also.

Edit: Here's a [link](https://www.quora.com/in/How-do-I-solve-arg-z-i-z+i-pi-4) with the same answer as my answer above.

Comment: But $$arc(z)=\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$ if $z=a+bi$

Comment: $a,b$ are real numbers, and $i^2=-1$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I took tan(pi/4) = 1 while solving

Comment: You've shown that every point that satisfies the condition lies on the circle, but what you're saying is that every point on the circle satisfies the condition, a stronger statement.

Comment: @saulspatz But why does this method eliminate the other points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying we get

$$ \frac{z+i}{z-i} = \frac{x^2+y^2-1+2xi}{x^2+(y-1)^2} $$

Therefore

$$ \arg\left( \frac{z+i}{z-1} \right) = \arctan\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2-1} \right) = \frac{\pi}{4} $$

Or

$$ \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2-1} = 1 $$

An argument of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ implies that both the real and imaginary parts of  the complex number $w=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ have to be positive, therefore $2x > 0$ and $x^2+y^2-1>0$

This implies your locus is the set of points such that
$$ \{x,y: (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 2; x > 0, x^2+y^2 > 1 \} $$

Do you see why it's not the whole circle?

**EDIT:** Here's a graph of the locus

[image: 1]

Note the center at $(1,0)$. You only include part of the circle on the right of the $y$-axis (where $x>0$). This turns out to be $3/4$ of the entire circle.

I'll leave it to you to write a formal proof.

Comment: I follow upto "lies in the first quadrant".

Comment: @SmarthBansal If $x+iy$ is in the first quadrant, $x\ge 0, y \ge 0$  That's the definition of "first quadrant," isn't it?

Comment: I see, so it's actually the portion of the circle in the first quadrant?

Comment: @Dylan I took the liberty of inserting the -1 you accidentally omitted in the very last inequality.

Comment: @Dylan If the portion of the circle in the first quadrant is considered then it's perimeter comes out to be half of the actual answer.

Comment: I mean to say that the real and imaginary parts of the number $\frac{z+i}{z-i}$ have to both be positive.

Comment: @Dylan But the answer given is 3/4 of the circle.

Comment: You're still not understanding me... Look at the inequalities I described. Try to draw a picture.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks. I actually meant to write $x^2+y^2>1$

Comment: @Dylan Yes, that's exactly the right picture.  I was trying to say that your earlier comment that the locus is half the circle (not three-quarters) was mistaken.  Sorry for not expressing myself more clearly.

Comment: @saulspatz I never said the locus was half the circle. That's OP's misunderstanding

Comment: @Dylan My bad.  I got the signatures mixed up.  Sorry.

Comment: @SmarthBansal See if my edit makes more sense.

Comment: @Dylan +1 nice answer, i finally got it. So when opening an argument function I must always take precautions of where it lies. Thanks

Comment: I feel like giving a bounty to this answer because only because of your answer, I'm able to understand the restriction in locus when using argument!